Is is possible to check if a giving class has at least one public method?
Is it possible somehow (at compile time) with any C++ standard?
Pseudo example
struct S1 { void can(){}; };
struct S2{};
class C1 { void be(){}; };
class C2 { public: void any_name(){}};

static_assert(check<S1>);
static_assert(!check<S2>);
static_assert(!check<C1>);
static_assert(check<C2>);


Pretty sure the  answer is no until we get reflection.

No, c++ don't have reflection.

Related/dupe: Why does C++ not have reflection?

@user12002570 Why close and comment?

Not out of the box, but boost has a reflection library - you might have some luck there (but you need to be able to annotate the said classes).

All four of these classes have public constructors and destructors btw. If there was a particular reason you needed to do this, there might be a different way to do what you want.

what's the intention? and what do you mean by "public method", there are compiler generated special functions, there are user declared functions, there are user defined functions -- you can be sure there are always some of those.

@Artyer Yes, you're correct, I've got to add "user defined"
